# Project Server 2010 Active Directory synchronization issues

Tags: 2010, project-server

Standard Information:PSI Entry Point: 

Project User:

Correlation Id: 

PWA Site URL: 

SSP Name: Project Web Application Service

PSError: NoError (0)

> A resource could not be updated during Project Server Active
>   Directory Synchronization because a duplicate windows account name
>   conflict occured that could not be resolved. Resource GUID:
>   e668278d-7300-4da1-a684-f3e37c4406e5. Resource Name xxxxxx. Windows
>   Account: xxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at resource tables in DBs (I think published-DB) for this "Windows Account".
If this one you try to synchronize belongs to other inactive resource, your only chance to solve it is to delete the entry in the DB (highly unrecommended!).